# how to return data from php to jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm new to ajax, but I really want to learn. I have set up a form (formidable pro) which is submitted via ajax. In the submit button I have on onclick function:

`<div class="frm_submit">
<input id="btn-max-hyp" onclick="add_customer()" type="submit" value="[button_label]" [button_action] />
<img class="frm_ajax_loading" src="[frmurl]/images/ajax_loader.gif" alt="Sending"/>
</div>`

My custom js file:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#form_maxhyp').on("submit", add_customer);

function add_customer () {
var form_maxhyp = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: frontendajax.ajaxurl,
data: form_maxhyp,

success: function(data)
{
 $("#test").html(data);
}
});

return false;

}
});
```

And last the code in my function.php

```html
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_frontend_ajax_javascript_file' );
function add_frontend_ajax_javascript_file()
{
 wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_custom_script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/ajax-javascript.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_localize_script( 'ajax_custom_script', 'frontendajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}

add_action('wp_ajax_add_customer', 'add_customer');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_customer', 'add_customer');
function add_customer($entry_id, $form_id)
{
 if ( $form_id == 6 ) 
 {
  global $wpdb, $frmdb;
  $form1 = '6';
        $value = $_POST['item_meta'][222];

/* a lot of if and else statements */

/* Echo values */
  echo "'".$value. "'";
 }
 
 die();
}
```

I want to set the value to my div.
In the console log I get an error: ReferenceError: add_customer is not defined.

Probably it's something really simple that I'm just not seeing. What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: remove `onclick="add_customer()"`, you don't need that. on the PHP side, your callback function does not receive any parameters, grab them from get/post variables

Comment: removing this did the trick. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

in your custom js file you have this :

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#form_maxhyp').on("submit", add_customer);`

in this case `add_customer` is read as a variable.

change it to this:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#form_maxhyp').on("submit", add_customer());`

to make the call to your function!